# Run PHP script and also submit form to URL

Tags: php, html, forms, crm

I have a HTML registration form, that adds users to the content management system using PHP. I need to integrate this into my a Customer Relationship Management tool (AgileCRM).

This code here will allow a user to register, which will submit the form and create the user using PHP.

```
<?php
if ($input->post->submit) {
  //create user
}
?>
<form action='./' accept-charset='UTF-8' autocomplete='off' method='post'>
    <input type='text' name='username' placeholder='Username'>
    <input type='text' name='email' placeholder='Email'>
    <input type='password' name='password' placeholder='Password'>
    <button type='submit' name='submit' value='register'>Register</button>
</form>
```

Then this code will do what I want in the CRM

```
<link href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/agilecrm/forms/v1/agile-form-min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<form class="form-view  " id="agile-form" action="https://agiledomain.agilecrm.com/formsubmit" style="max-width:450px;" method="post">
<fieldset>

<!-- Form Name -->
<legend class="agile-hide-formname">Registration Form</legend>
<p class="agile-form-description"></p>
<div style="display: none; height: 0px; width: 0px;">
<input type="hidden" id="_agile_form_name" name="_agile_form_name" value="Registration Form">
<input type="hidden" id="_agile_domain" name="_agile_domain" value="AGILECRMDOMAIN">
<input type="hidden" id="_agile_api" name="_agile_api" value="AGILECRMAPIKEY">
<input type="hidden" id="_agile_redirect_url" name="_agile_redirect_url" value="#">
<input type="hidden" id="_agile_document_url" name="_agile_document_url" value="">
<input type="hidden" id="_agile_confirmation_msg" name="_agile_confirmation_msg" value="Thank you for signing up!">
<input type="hidden" id="_agile_form_id_tags" name="tags" value="">

<input type="hidden" id="_agile_form_id" name="_agile_form_id" value="AGILECRMID">
</div>
<!-- Text input-->
<div class="agile-group required-control">
  <label class="agile-label" for="username">Username<span class="agile-span-asterisk"> *</span></label>
  <div class="agile-field-xlarge agile-field">
    <input maxlength="250" id="username" name="Username" type="text" placeholder="" class="agile-height-default" required="">
  </div>
  <div class="agile-custom-clear"></div>
</div>
<!-- Text input-->
<div class="agile-group required-control">
  <label class="agile-label" for="email">Email<span class="agile-span-asterisk"> *</span></label>
  <div class="agile-field-xlarge agile-field">
    <input maxlength="250" id="email" name="email" type="email" placeholder="" class="agile-height-default" required="">
  </div>
  <div class="agile-custom-clear"></div>
</div>
<!-- Password input-->
<div class="agile-group required-control">
  <label class="agile-label" for="password">Password Input<span class="agile-span-asterisk"> *</span></label>
  <div class="agile-field-xlarge agile-field">
    <input maxlength="250" id="password" name="password" type="password" placeholder="" class="agile-height-default" required="">
  </div>
  <div class="agile-custom-clear"></div>
</div>

<!--recaptcha aglignment-->
<!-- Button -->
<div class="agile-group">
  <label class="agile-label">&nbsp;</label>
  <div class="agile-field agile-button-field">
    <button type="submit" class="agile-button">Submit</button>
    <br><span id="agile-error-msg"></span>
  </div>
</div>

</fieldset>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function(a){var b=a.onload,p=true;isCaptcha=false;if(p){a.onload="function"!=typeof b?function(){try{_agile_load_form_fields()}catch(a){}}:function(){b();try{_agile_load_form_fields()}catch(a){}}};var formLen=document.forms.length;for(i=0;i<formLen;i++){if(document.forms.item(i).getAttribute("id")== "agile-form"){a.document.forms.item(i).onsubmit=function(a){a.preventDefault();try{_agile_synch_form_v5(this)}catch(b){this.submit()}}}}})(window);
</script>
```

So basically I'd like to join the functionality of these two forms together, so submit the form to AgileCRM and also run the PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with jQuery ajax
and give your first form an id then it will be submitted after agile form.

```
 $('#agile-form').submit(function(){
    // show that something is loading
    $('#response').html("<b>Loading response...</b>");

    /*
     * 'post_receiver.php' - where you will pass the form data
     * $(this).serialize() - to easily read form data
     * function(data){... - data contains the response from post_receiver.php
     */
    $.ajax({
        type  :'POST',
        url : "https://agiledomain.agilecrm.com/formsubmit", 
        async: false,
        data: $(this).serialize()
    })
    .done(function(data){ 
        //give your first form an id and submit it for eg:firsForm
     $('#firstForm').submit();
    })
    .fail(function() {
        // just in case posting your form failed
        alert( "Posting failed." );     
    });
    // to prevent refreshing the whole page page
    return false;
});
```

Comment: I haven't had much experience with jQuery/ajax. I don't quote follow everything, could you provide some more detail.
This is what I have got currently https://pastebin.com/r51aKMfE

Comment: what result are you getting ??

Comment: I am getting 'posting failed'.